# Displaying 3D rotating object on a cameraPreview?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I created 3D object and I'm also displaying a camera preview. The CameraPreview is

displayed on a SurfaceView definded in the XML file, and the 3D object is displayed on a

framelayout defined in the XML file. I want to display the rotating 3D object over the

CameraPreview, but when I run the App, the CameraPreview is being displayed for few

seconds and after that the activity shows the 3D rotating object independent from the

cameraPreview, I mean, the rotating 3D object is not displayed on the Camerapreview

surface. Is there any way to fix this mistake?

Your help is highlu appreciated.

**Code**:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mpinfo);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);   
        surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);           
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(previewing){
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
    }

        if (camera != null){
        try {
              camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
              camera.startPreview();
              previewing = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        camera = android.hardware.Camera.open();    
        //Create an Instance with this Activity
        glSurface = new GLSurfaceView(this);

        //Set our own Renderer
        glSurface.setRenderer(new Lesson05());

        //Set the GLSurface as View to this Activity

        fl01 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fl01);

        //setContentView(glSurface);
        //fl01.addView(cameraSurface);

        fl01.addView(glSurface);
    }
```

**xml File**

```
<FrameLayout 
                android:id="@+id/fl01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </FrameLayout>
            <SurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/camerapreview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648221)! Hope this helps :)